# PHP: weird usort bug

Tags: php, zend-framework, usort

Everything works fine on my local machine. But when uploading this piece of code to my live server I'm getting a weird warning ...

```
usort($modules, array('util_SortItem', 'ByOrder'));
```

Causes this warning:

> Warning: include_once(sc3lycp6hmyab.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/www/xxx/web/private/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'sc3lycp6hmyab.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /opt/www/xxx/web/private/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

When I remove the usort from my code the warnings disapear.

Any ideas on how I can get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to sort out the isue but I got rid of it by merging two queries and sorting on my SQL server.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the `usort`, but with the `ByOrder` method of the `Util_SortItem` class that you are telling `usort()` to call.

You should take a look into the file where that class is defined to see what it does to trigger the error.

One possibility is that it tries to include a class that doesn't exist, which triggers Zend's Autoloader; the other that Zend is trying to create some sort of cache file.

Comment: If I add a die; statement before the first line of code in the ByOrder method, I still receive the warning.

Comment: @brechtvhb weird. Then this must be something that Zend does when loading the class (or trying to do so). Is `util_SortItem` a class? How is it loaded?

Comment: It is a very simple class: `<?php
class util_SortItem {
 var $a;
 var $b;

 public function SortItem($objectA, $objectB) {
 $this->a = $objectA;
    $this->b = $objectB;
 }

 public function ByOrder($m, $n) {
 print_r($m);
    if ($m->Order == $n->Order) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($m->Order < $n->Order) ? 1 : -1;
 }
}
?>`

Comment: @brechtvhb How are you loading it, through the autoloader or using `include()`? Have you configured Zend Framework's path for storing cache and temporary files? I'*m no ZF Guru, but I think I remember it had options for that somewhere. The file name looks like a temporary file

Comment: I'm loading it through the autoloader. I have configured nothing about cache files but I'll look into it.

Comment: @brechtvhb the autoloader seems to be doing something funny, but I don't know why. It looks like ZF is creating a temporary file for some reason. Maybe one of the resident ZF experts knows what this is, be sure to bump the question in a few hours when sun rises in the US.

Comment: Allright :) What makes this even more weird is that it **does** sort like it should.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like those spammer names. I'd guess it's not related whatsoever. I **think** you might have something unescaped in your application and it results in someone trying to exploit it ;)

Comment: Yup, that occurred to me, too: It could be a malware injection accidentally caught by the Zend Autoloader. On the other hand, it could be a random cache file name. Worth checking out nevertheless

Comment: Zend cache files start with `zend-cache-` so it's not a cache file.

Comment: I doubt it is a malware injection ... the site is just online and the url is unkown yet.